# Congratulations to DaftWullie for reaching a reputation of 50,000!

Tags: discussion

Any day now, the Quantum Computing Stack Exchange will have its first user to have reached 50k reputation!

I, for one, appreciate DaftWullie's many wonderful and varied contributions to this site.  His patience and care is clear.  I remember he offered some welcoming comments to me when I first started contributing.  I know he's done the same for many others.

No one is an island and we all stand on the shoulders of giants; also, people have varying amounts of time and energy and interest in contributing.  Furthermore 50,000 is just an arbitrary number for funny internet Monopoly-money reputation points.  But even still, it's an achievement to be highlighted!

Some of my favorite contributions of his, and why:

- [Arbitrary powers of NOT and SWAP](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3793/arbitrary-powers-of-not-and-swap) is a posting that he asked and answered as a bit of a "FAQ" at the beginnings of QCSE.  This helps explore the relation between these operators and their respective powers. Similar questions have often been asked, and this is a great pointer for such questions;
- His sermon on the [Significance of The Church of the Higher Hilbert space](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1657/significance-of-the-church-of-the-higher-hilbert-space/1659#1659) helped make me a convert, as I often go there myself to pray; and
- [What are examples of Hamiltonian simulation problems that are BQP-complete?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/what-are-examples-of-hamiltonian-simulation-problems-that-are-bqp-complete/2081#2081) was a great deconstruction of BQP and why (local) Hamiltonian simulation is both in BQP and BQP-hard, with precedents even back to Feynman.

Thanks for helping to make QCSE what it is, @DaftWullie!

Comment: This very moment precisely 50,000. Congratulations! This needs to be celebrated with a piece of chocolate cake!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. I have to say that I hadn't even noticed!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Any time!

Comment: @DaftWullie Crivens! The kelda be proud o' ye!

Answer (score 3):

I think posts like this are very helpful for the community! This is quite an achievement.